# Pause until event is complete before next loop iteration (Simon Game)

Tags: javascript, arrays

all. Working on creating a Simon game, similar to the version found here: https: [Simon Game](http:////www.memozor.com/simon-games/simon-game) (I suggest going to go play the game so you have an understanding of how the game is supposed to work and what I'm wanting to do.)

Right now I have an array called "gamePattern" setup so that it holds a list of randomly generated values from 1-4. These values determine what color button needs to be guessed by the user, and is associatted to a particular button and button sound. So, for instance, when the game starts, a number will be generated into the gamePattern array, whichw ill trigger an animation on the buttons I have associated with the value and the sound associated with the value. The user then needs to guess which button to press. If the user guesses the correct button, then a new value is generated into the next item of the gamePattern array, the user then clicks the button associated with the value in item 1 of the array and the button associated with the value in item 2 of the array. Their guess is checked and then a new number will be generated, and so on and so forth until the users guess is wrong.

What I'm trying to due is to loop through the gamePattern array and play the sound and button animation associated with the value in each item of the array, however; I want it to pause until the animation and sound are done playing before it performs the next iteration of the loop and plays the next sound and animation (fade-in/fade-out of the button).

Here is my code for the game (please be nice in your critique. I'm a new programmer, and so the code is bound to look pretty ugly and be written poorly. Hopefully not so bad that you can't understand it):

---

```
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
var level = 0;

//Sets audio file name of audio file and plays audio file
function playChosenColorSound(chosenColor){
    var audioFilePath = 'sounds/' + chosenColor + '.mp3';
    var sound = new Audio(audioFilePath);
    sound.play();
}


function usersChoice(e){
    var userChosenColor = e.target.id; //Determines what button color the user pressed
    userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);
    playChosenColorSound(userChosenColor); //Plays sound of users chosen button color
    $("#" + userChosenColor).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200); //Animates button user pressed with mouse.
    

    //Turns off users ability to click a button until new sequence is generated
    $(".btn").off("click"); 
    checkAnswer();
}

//Generates random number used to choose next button color from buttonColors array.
function nextSequence(){

    level++; //Increases level count

    $("#level-title").html(`Level: ${level}`); //Changes H1 title to show level

    //Choses random color from buttonColors array from random generated number.
    var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[Math.round(Math.random()*3)];

    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

    //Fades in/out the buttons associated with the colors listed in the gamePattern array in sequence
    for (var i = 0; i < gamePattern.length; i++){
        $("#" + gamePattern[i]).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200,playChosenColorSound(gamePattern[i]));
    }
    

    $(".btn").click(usersChoice); //Gives user ability to click button after gamePattern animations has played

}

function checkAnswer(){

    console.log(gamePattern);
    console.log(userClickedPattern);

    if(userClickedPattern[userClickedPattern.length - 1] === gamePattern[gamePattern.length - 1]){
        nextSequence();
    }
    else{
        wrongAnswer();
    }
    
}

function start(){
    nextSequence();
    $(document).off("keypress");
}

//Let's user know that their choice was wrong. 
function wrongAnswer(){
    var audioFilePath = 'sounds/wrong.mp3';
    var sound = new Audio(audioFilePath);
    sound.play();
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
    $("#level-title").html("That was the wrong answer. \n Press a Key to Play Again");
    $(document).keypress(resetGame);
}

//Resets level value, gamePattern and userClickedPattern array so user can play again.
function resetGame(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "#011F3F");
    gamePattern = [];
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level = 0;
    start();
}

$(document).keypress(start);
```

---

The loop in question is within the nextSequence() function.

Thank you so much, all. Appreciate any feedback, hints, or advice you can provide.

Comment: [this](https://xstate.js.org/docs/) and [this](https://raganwald.com/2018/02/23/forde.html) you might find useful

Answer (score 0):

The Audio api has an [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event. You can use that to resolve a Promise. You can do the same with animations ([animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)). I'm not sure if your sound and animation durations are the same or if you need both to finish before going to the next loop, but you can then call those Promises in `Promise.all` and then just continue with the next sequence.

Maybe something like this:

```
generateSoundPromise(color) {
  return new Promise(resolve) {
    const audioFilePath = `sounds/${chosenColor}.mp3`;
    const sound = new Audio(audioFilePath);

    sound.addEventListener('ended', resolve);
    sound.play();
  }
}

generateAnimationPromise(color) {
  return new Promise(resolve) {
    yourElement.addEventListener('animationend', resolve);
  }
}

await Promise.all([
  generateSoundPromise('blue'),
  generateAnimationPromise('blue'),
]);

// Perform next sequence
```